# Formview paging controls not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a formview which displays a recordset based on a parameter supplied by a dropdownlist.  The formview has "AllowPaging = True".

The first time the dropdownlist is changed, the formview shows the (correct) first row of the retrieved recordset but the paging controls are missing.  From that point on, when the dropdownlist is changed, the formview works as expected, showing the correct page controls.

What do I need to do to have the formview show the page controls the first time it is activated?

Answer (score 2):

These kind of errors are sometimes due to a missing explicit binding call such as:

```
formview.DataBind();
```

Try this after the first change of the dropdownlist.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answering!  I fixed my original problem with some kind of work around (I forget what!), but if I can find it again I'll try out your answer.